# compare different pandas dataframes to find matching rows

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have two dataframes: One contains of name and year.

```
**name** **year**

ram       1873

rob       1900
```

Second contains names and texts.

```
**name** **text**

ram      A good kid

ram     He was born on 1873

rob     He is tall

rob     He is 12 yrs old

rob     His father died at 1900
```

I want to find the indices of the rows of second dataframe where the name of second dataframe matches with name of the first df and the text in second df contains the year in first df.

The result should be indices 1,4

My Code:

```
ind_list = []
for ind1, old in enumerate(A.name):
    for ind2, new in enumerate(B.name):
        if A.name[ind1] == B.name[ind2]:
            if A.year[ind1] in B.text[ind2]:
                ind_list.append(ind2)
```

Any better way to write the above code?

Comment: I have added the _python_ tag, this one should always be provided as companion of a _python-*_ tag.

Answer (score 2):

Here is what we start with.

```py
In [16]: df1
Out[16]:
  name  year
0  ram  1873
1  rob  1900

In [17]: df2
Out[17]:
  name                     text
0  ram               A good kid
1  ram      He was born on 1873
2  rob               He is tall
3  rob         He is 12 yrs old
4  rob  His father died at 1900
```

What you probably want to do is merge your two DataFrames.  If you're familiar with SQL, this is just like a table join.  The `pd.merge` step essentially "adds" the columns from `df1` to `df2` by checking where the two DataFrames match on the column "name".  Then, once you have the columns you want ("year" and "text") matching according to the "name" column, we apply the function `lambda x: str(x.year) in x.text` (which checks if the year is present in the text) across the rows (`axis=1`).

```py
In [18]: cond = pd.merge(
    ...:     left=df2,
    ...:     right=df1,
    ...:     how="left",
    ...:     left_on="name",
    ...:     right_on="name",
    ...: ).apply(lambda x: str(x.year) in x.text, axis=1)
```

This gives us a Series which has the same index as your second DataFrame, and contains boolean values telling you if your desired condition is met or not.

```py
In [19]: cond
Out[19]:
0    False
1     True
2    False
3    False
4     True
dtype: bool
```

Then, we filter your Series to where the condition is true, and give the index, optionally converting it to a list.

```py
In [20]: cond[cond].index
Out[20]: Int64Index([1, 4], dtype='int64')
In [21]: cond[cond].index.tolist()
Out[21]: [1, 4]
```

If all you need later on is to iterate over the indices you've gotten, `In [18]` and `In [20]` will suffice.

Comment: Thanks.. this is good. But if I apply it for different data-frames the 1/3 rd of the total number of rows from cond dataframe is NaN. What could be the possible reason

Comment: I can't know for sure, but if, for example, `df2` contains names not present in `df1`, then those rows will probably get filled in with NaN during the join/merge.  Depending of your use case, you might treat those cases differently, but if I interpret your question strictly, then replacing `str(x.year) in x.text` with `(str(int(x.year)) in x.text) if not pd.isnull(x.year) else False` would probably be the best way to go (converting the NaN to False so they don't appear in the final list of indices).